# Google Play Services Location throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, location, google-play-services

I am trying to run a service that tracks a users location using the Google Play Location Services. I've followed the [Android Developers Google Play] (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) instructions but currently have a crashing app.

I am using the android emulator AVD with a Google API target (17).

I have

1) Installed the Google Play Services SDK

2) Made a copy of the Google Play services library project, imported it into my Eclipse workspace, and referenced it in my current app, using these [instructions] (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

**I am not sure whether or not I have to add anything to the Manifest**

Some background on my app structure: I have created a Location Services class with all of the error handling, and am calling that class' methods via a service. My app is currently crashing when I call the:

`GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);`

command which is in the `servicesConnected()` which is the first instance I call anything Google Play related. So basically, where I am at: I am trying to call the method checking if Google Play services is available, and the app is crashing on:

```
 08-19 03:51:19.464: E/AndroidRuntime(1112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service 
      com.scarr025.zwilio.AdventureService@40d24920 with Intent { flg=0x4 
      cmp=com.scarr025.zwilio/.AdventureService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Please help!!**

Code is below:

Google Play Services Class

```
public class AdventureLocator extends FragmentActivity implements
            GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mLocClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mContext = this;
}

public void startConnection() {
    mLocClient.connect();
}

public Location getLastLocation() {
    return mLocClient.getLastLocation();
}

// Method that encapsulates the check for Google Play services
public boolean servicesConnected() {
    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d("$$AdventureLocator$$", "In servicesConnected; Google Play services is available (returned true).");
        // Continue
        return true;
    // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    } else {
        // Get the error code
        // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                resultCode,
                this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

        // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
        if (errorDialog != null) {
            // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            // Set the dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
            // Show the error dialog in the DialogFragment
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
        }
        return false;
    }
    ...
```

Manifest File

```
...
        <service
        android:name=".AdventureService"
        android:label="@string/title_adventure_service" >
    </service> 
    <activity
        android:name=".AdventureLocator"
        android:label="@string/title_adventure_locator" >
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: consider to add an internet permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left out the library referencing in the Manifest File

"After you've added the Google Play services library as a dependency for your app project, open your app's manifest file and add the following tag as a child of the  element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Once you've set up your project to reference the library project, you can begin developing features with the Google Play services APIs."